# How i fit the entire text and image to fit in this card component

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a carousel in which there is a right and left slider. the text and image coming in the card component are not fit. actually there are surpassing the container i want to make them fit.

[image: Text and photo in card component]
in this component is it not coming in card instead only some item. i want them to assign in proper order and within the frame but not happening

**INDEX**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="slide hi-slide">
      <div class="hi-prev"></div>
      <div class="hi-next"></div>

      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
            <img src="1.jfif" alt="Img 1" height="90px" />
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                the bulk of the card's content.
              </p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
            <img src="images (1).jfif" alt="Img 1" height="90px" />
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                the bulk of the card's content.
              </p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
            <img src="images (1).png" alt="Img 1" height="90px" />
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                the bulk of the card's content.
              </p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
            <img src="images.jfif" alt="Img 1" height="90px" />
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                the bulk of the card's content.
              </p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
            <img src="images.png" alt="Img 1" height="90px" />
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                the bulk of the card's content.
              </p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
            <img src="images.png" alt="Img 1" height="90px" />
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                the bulk of the card's content.
              </p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
            <img src="images.png" alt="Img 1" height="90px" />
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                the bulk of the card's content.
              </p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
            <img src="images.png" alt="Img 1" height="90px" />
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                the bulk of the card's content.
              </p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(".slide").hiSlide();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**STYLE**

```
body {
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

body {
  background-image: url(ur.jpg);
}

h1 {
  margin: 150px auto 30px auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}

.hi-slide {
  position: relative;
  width: 754px;
  height: 292px;
  margin: 115px auto 0;
}

.hi-slide .hi-next,
.hi-slide .hi-prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  border-radius: 50px;

  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: black;
  transition: all 0.6s;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.hi-slide .hi-next:hover,
.hi-slide .hi-prev:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.hi-slide .hi-prev {
  left: -60px;
}

.hi-slide .hi-prev::before {
  content: "<";
}

.hi-slide .hi-next {
  right: -60px;
}

.hi-slide .hi-next::before {
  content: ">";
}

.hi-slide > ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 754px;
  height: 292px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.hi-slide > ul > li {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  left: 377px;
  top: 146px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  background-color: #333;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* .hi-slide > ul > li > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
} */
```

**SCRIPT**

```
(function ($) {
  var slide = function (ele, options) {
    var $ele = $(ele);

    var setting = {
      speed: 1000,

      interval: 10000,
    };

    $.extend(true, setting, options);

    var states = [
      {
        $zIndex: 1,
        width: 120,
        height: 150,
        top: 69,
        left: 134,
        $opacity: 0.2,
      },
      { $zIndex: 2, width: 130, height: 170, top: 59, left: 0, $opacity: 0.4 },
      {
        $zIndex: 3,
        width: 170,
        height: 218,
        top: 35,
        left: 110,
        $opacity: 0.7,
      },
      { $zIndex: 4, width: 224, height: 288, top: 0, left: 263, $opacity: 1 },
      {
        $zIndex: 3,
        width: 170,
        height: 218,
        top: 35,
        left: 470,
        $opacity: 0.7,
      },
      {
        $zIndex: 2,
        width: 130,
        height: 170,
        top: 59,
        left: 620,
        $opacity: 0.4,
      },
      {
        $zIndex: 1,
        width: 120,
        height: 150,
        top: 69,
        left: 500,
        $opacity: 0.2,
      },
    ];

    var $lis = $ele.find("li");
    var timer = null;

    $ele.find(".hi-next").on("click", function () {
      next();
    });
    $ele.find(".hi-prev").on("click", function () {
      states.push(states.shift());
      move();
    });
    $ele
      .on("mouseenter", function () {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = null;
      })
      .on("mouseleave", function () {
        autoPlay();
      });

    move();
    autoPlay();

    function move() {
      $lis.each(function (index, element) {
        var state = states[index];
        $(element)
          .css("zIndex", state.$zIndex)
          .finish()
          .animate(state, setting.speed)
          .find("img")
          .css("opacity", state.$opacity);
      });
    }

    function next() {
      states.unshift(states.pop());
      move();
    }

    function autoPlay() {
      timer = setInterval(next, setting.interval);
    }
  };

  $.fn.hiSlide = function (options) {
    $(this).each(function (index, ele) {
      slide(ele, options);
    });

    return this;
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the width of li and the card div is different. To fix this either increase the width of li element or remove `width:18rem` from card div.